# Sorting Algorithm: Block sorting with constant cost

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Doesn't have to do anything with [this block sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946545/block-sort-algorithm)!

This is a quite practical problem. Assume you sort a file manually in a text editor. You surely will cut out larger, already sorted blocks and paste them elsewhere. *Your* cost (we assume that marking the text takes constant time, even if it is large!) is hereby defined as O(1) for each of these operations, even if the "real" cost is O(n). For example:

text: 512678439. Cut 678, paste before 9, get 512436789. The blocks don't have to be sorted: Cut 43, paste before 6, get 512436789 (the same). The data only must be adjacent.

In this cost model, you surely are much faster than O(n log n). I would guess the worst case (reversing) is O(n) and the average O(log n). Can you give me a reference? (Googling is quite hopeless, since block sort usually means the stuff linked above and the cost model is nonstandard. But surely I'm not inventing this idea.)

Comment: I think you are under-estimating the algorithmic complexity that the editor needs to have in order to support e.g. `Cut 678, paste before 9`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: if I am right, the question is about the manual operations (could be made with paper strips).

Comment: It is not sufficient for a block to be already sorted, what matters is that it is sorted in the global order. IMO, log n is a very optimistic estimate, I'd rather believe in expected O(N). Your question has a connection to natural merge sort, I guess. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort Also with the number of misplaced elements, and with adaptive sorting.

Comment: Another issue is to know whether it is feasible or not to find the smallest number of operations for a given initial configuration.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Indeed, and it is also interesting how it compares to the number of operations the "true" algorithm (with "internal"  cost model - moving a n-block costs O(n), not O(1)) has.